# Error with Universal Image Loader version 1.9.2

Tags: android, amazon-cloudfront, universal-image-loader

I implemented UIL in my project. I am getting following error:

```
ImageLoader﹕ Unable to resolve host "d1l025sgu0zsw9.cloudfront.net": No address associated with hostname
```

My permissions in manifest are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Why I am getting this error?

UPDATE: It seems to be a problem with CloudFront. If I don't use it, S3 url works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Error is with your url,thats why your are getting

```
ImageLoader﹕ Unable to resolve host "d1l025sgu0zsw9.cloudfront.net": No address associated with hostname
```

## In your logcat:

you are are also getting:

```
hostname= null
```

if my above statement is true,then

## possible reason is:

```
your url  you are passing to the query string is not starting with your hostname like www.abc.com. or you have to pass some headers in your http hit.
```

## solution

```
either make your string  by harcode the host name  like : www. +   your url or pass the requested headers. your manifest permissions are fine.
```

Comment: Url is http://d1l025sgu0zsw9.cloudfront.net/icons/alfabe_ikon/ABC.png so it is valid.

Comment: yeah,and i think its also working when you directly hit this to your browser.right?

Comment: use http://www.d1l025sgu0zsw9.cloudfront.net/icons/alfabe_ikon/ABC.png, give a try nd let me know the results.

Comment: Unable to resolve host "www.d1l025sgu0zsw9.cloudfront.net": No address associated with hostname

Comment: then there must be some http headers required by the server,ask from server team,do they require header if yes then they will tell you.

Comment: or if this issue is with universal image lib then go for AndroidQuery.i highly recommend your about  that.even if  you have to download 5k images from server then it will be working well.